# When does OpenCoin Inc intend to make the Ripple server code public?

Tags: ripple, server

Is there a definite timeline or not? Thank you.

Comment: I suspect that the timeline is being kept a secret - quoting from bitcoin talk - `it is also in their best interests not to release the source code at first. They need to wait until Ripple has critical mass so that it will be impractical for a hard fork to divest the owners of their 100 billion XRP premine.` I don't work for OpenCoin, so I don't really know.

Comment: Fair enough - though how is it supposed to reach critical mass if the server is being run on a handful of sites so far? Also, unless the entire source code is open for inspection, there's a cold chance in hell it will be widely adopted.

Comment: You state the obvious sir. Critical mass means enough gateways and users who will use them to actually do payments.

Comment: Server is at minimum an order of magnitude more complex than the client and client was (or still is) pretty buggy. It seems it takes them months to fix relatively simple bugs. Server is probably a year away IMO.

Comment: It is the obvious we miss most often Alex, as it is too close to our noses.

Answer (score 9):

We have publicly stated that we don't expect the code to be made publicly available in less than two months and that we would consider it a failure if we didn't make the code publicly available before the end of the year.

Right now, we've received a lot of public feedback and are trying to make changes responsive to that feedback. See [this github issue](https://github.com/rippleFoundation/ripple-client/issues/748) for an example. It will be very hard to make significant changes after the source code is public.

(I'm an employee of Opencoin and one of the designers of the Ripple payment network. I'm speaking only for myself.)

Comment: I would appreciate a description of how it works, encryption,etc.  My request via twitter to attend the conference hasn't been replied to by your marketing department, so I (as a developer) will not be able to design products and solutions around your product.

Comment: @makerofthings7 You can just show up and we'll let you in.

Answer (score 4):

OpenCoin (now called Ripple Labs Inc.) open sourced the Ripple server code on Sept 25th 2013.

Announcement: https://ripple.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3718
Source: https://github.com/ripple/

Answer (score 3):

There's no timeline, but they say it's "[top priority](https://github.com/rippleFoundation/ripple-client/issues/581)".

Comment: That being said... personally until they go open ripple is no longer interesting to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fixed open-sourcing date, there is certain large enhancements that OC wants to be in the initial release. My best guesstimate is that there is an 80% chance of the release before the end of the year and 50% chance before September.

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion is that the server code isn't ready yet. Nor is the client. Ripple is a very complex and ambituous piece of software. I think they need more programmers and a lot more polish and bugfixing before it is released. I consider myself at least of average intelligence and quite frankly, the order book in the client confuses the shit out of me. And I'm a huge fan of Ripple!